# CSS change height of table cell with <a> in it

Tags: html, css

I have a single column table with multiple rows some of which have a-tag links in them, the others just plain text. I can change the height of any cells except the ones that have a-tags in them; they remain unaffected.

```
#table tr td{
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

This code changes the height of all the cells to 20px except the cells that have a-tags in them. They remain around 30px or so no matter what I do. How can I get the height of those cells to change too?

Comment: You really should post the markup or any css that may affect your anchor tags. You could have margins or padding or font-size applied that make it taller than 20px.

Comment: You can't make the cell smaller than its contents. Your link is probably higher than 20px.

Answer (score 0):

Define `display:block` is your `<a>` tag because `<a>` an `inline` element. An `inline` element did not take `width` , `height` ,`vertical margin` & `vertical padding`

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow: hidden`

If that doesn't work, please post some of your markup or make a jsfiddle :)